# How to get UserPrincipal from IPrincipal in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#

In C# ASP.NET, I'm trying to get the current user display name like "Tom Jones" and not "Jones, Tom". I saw this code

```
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, User.Identity.Name);
```

But the problem is that, it looks it up by name, and there could be multiple matches. How can I get it from a unique identifier?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbyidentity?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_UserPrincipal_FindByIdentity_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_IdentityType_System_String_